# validation failure when using mysql as dataSource in Corda

Tags: corda

I am running mysql as docker (mysql:8.0.20). Gradle task deployNodes fails with error :

Could not create the DataSource: Validation Failed:
     1 changes have validation failures
          columnDataType is required for renameColumn on mysql, migration/node-info.changelog-v3.xml::column_host_name::R3.Corda.

Can somebody help me with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see columnDataType is a required attribute for MySql. Corda does not support MySql and hence this is not tested against MySql so you could get these kinds of MySql specific errors.

If you are using Corda enterprise, you could set the runMigration flag to false(which will not run the schema automatically on the db), use the database management tool to manually generate the schema, make changes (add columnDataType to the schema), and then run it manually onto mysql db.

Below image is taken from https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/rename_column.html

[image]